# SVG low performance with rotated images

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, svg, d3.js

I am building an application in D3.js where I render several index cards (svg's) as one SVG. The user should be able to rotate those cards. For test purposes I used the drag behaviour for rotation

```
dragListener = d3.behavior.drag().on("dragstart", function(d){
        originX = parseInt(d3.select(this).select("image").attr("x"));
        originY = parseInt(d3.select(this).select("image").attr("y"));
    })
    .on("drag", function(d){
        counter++;
        if(counter > 360){
            counter = 0;
        }
        d3.select(this).attr("transform", 
            "rotate("+counter.toString()+","+(originX+150).toString()+","+(originY+90).toString()+")");
    });
```

which I provide to all index cards

```
var grp = svg.selectAll("g").data(arr);
var card = 
       grp.enter().append("g")
     //.attr("transform", function(d){ return "rotate(30,"+(d.x+150)+","+(d.y+90)+")";})
       .call(dragListener);
card.append("svg:image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "http://images.clipartlogo.com/files/images/22/227702/index-card_p")
    .attr("x", function(d){return d.x;})
    .attr("y", function(d){return d.y;})
    .attr("width", "300")
    .attr("height", "180");
```

The problem is, the more cards are already rotated the lower the performance when the user rotates a card . The FPS are around 8 in Chrome when all cards are rotated.
Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/45hdjkk0/6/
You can give all cards an initial rotation by removing the comments in line 32.

Am I doing something wrong or did I choose the wrong approach?

**UPDATE:**
After testing the same example on the Internet Explorer and on Firefox I have found out that Internet Explorer is the fastest among those three. Firefox is also very fast compared to Chrome. Is this a Chrome issue?

Answer (score 0):

Rotating any bitmap is computationally expensive.  I ran your fiddle in Firefox and Chrome. Though Firefox wasn't too bad, I did see some of the frame-rate slowdown in Chrome you spoke of.  There may not be a good solution if it has to be a png.  If it doesn't have to be png, you will get great performance rotating an svg composed of your combined graphics elements.

Edit: It looks like you really do want to rotate index cards, so I think you are in luck.  To illustrate what I'm talking about, comment out line 36 and then uncomment line 32.  Then see the rotation performance without the bitmap.  Then simply add in a few .attr("path", ...) lines to reproduce your index card and I bet the performance will rock.

Comment: Sorry, the cards were already SVG's. I forgot to mention it in the text. The performance is still very bad on Chrome compared to Internet Explorer.

Comment: When you download http://images.clipartlogo.com/files/images/22/227702/index-card_p and save it to a file, it's binary and says it's a png.

Comment: I've tested it without the image include and just draw one path and a white rectangle. The performance is still very bad on Chrome. With 100 of those white rectangles the fps are around 15 when I rotate them. Still Internet Explorer is the fastest.